# SwiftUI Button Action is not working but OnTapGesture

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swiftui, action

Hello I am trying to achieve simple functionality but somehow I am unable to use **action** of button, it never triggered, and not only in this code but also in my entire application, Am I doing something wrong or is it a glitch from SwiftUI. But **onTapGesture** works perfectly.

```
struct CounterView: View {
@State var counter = 0

var body: some View{

    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 8){
        Button(action: {
            //self.counter += 1
            }) {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }.padding(4.0)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4.0)
                    .stroke(lineWidth: 1.0)
                .trim()
            )
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.counter += 1
                }
        }}}
```

Help me resolve this issue.

Comment: your code is ok, both works in the simulator for me. maybe you have an other issue.
try running in device ?!

Comment: I am running it on simulator, and I am using beta version.

Comment: Restarting the simulator did the trick for me. My Xcode version is 11.3.1 might be some glitch in the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a size on the image

```swift
Image(systemName: "plus")
    .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .regular))
```